# rails updated_at not including time

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

in one module i have the fields updated_at and created_at

but in specific module the updated_at update with no time include

I add this fields by add the  t.timestamps on create the table

while checking the query i notice that the insert update query not included the time

for example this is the output query

```
INSERT INTO `logs` (`admin_id`, `admin_mail`, `admin_name`, `created_at`, `log_type_id`, `name`, `station_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES (3, 'xx@bb.com', 'xx@bbb.com', '13-10-16', 10, '+ abcdefghij...', 9096, '13-10-16')
```

what can be the reason that the insert command not included the time

thanks

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking for here - the insert query do includes both updated_at and created_at fields? Could you please reword the question so we know what is the problem?

Comment: yes the updated_at on the db is like 01-01-2013 00:00 the current time not included, and you can see on the insert command the date is '13-10-16' with no time, i what the time also like '13-10-16 16:46'

Comment: Ah, I see. Then, the set of standard questions: what db and which rails version are you using?

Comment: Please also try to run 'SHOW CREATE TABLE logs' in MySQL and attach Log model source code.

Comment: Did you check that the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns are in fact datetime ?

Comment: the db is mysql rails version 4 the db field are datetime, and i can change manually .

Comment: the db is mysql rails version 4 the db field are datetime, and i can change manually and add directly on the db the time .
another poing in the application i have more modules and on the other module the updated_at include the time this problem appear on one module only (LOG).
and the last thing i try running this code: (on the console)
l = Log.first
l.created_at = '13-10-16 16:23'
l.save
and the rails sql is: (with no time....)
UPDATE `logs` SET `created_at` = '13-10-16', `updated_at` = '13-10-16' WHERE....

Comment: CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `station_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin_mail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `log_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_event` text,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=251 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;